# UIImageView in sprite kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create an pause Menu when the pause button is pressed in Sprite Kit. This am i doing by creating an UIImageView. The problem is that the UIImageView is not being shown. How can i do this?

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{

    UIButton *pauseButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    [pauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pausedMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:pauseButton];

}




-(void)pausedMenu:(SKView *)view
{

    SKSpriteNode *menu = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"pausemenu"];
    //menu size is already image size (by default), no need to set it
    menu.position = CGPointMake((self.size.width - menu.size.width) * 0.5,
                            (self.size.height - menu.size.height) * 0.5);
    [self addChild:menu];
    self.scene.paused = YES;
    self.scene.view.paused = YES;


}
```

Comment: Why not use a SKSpriteNode instead of a UIImage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SpriteKit only, why to use UIImages?

```
SKSpriteNode *menu = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"pausemenu"];
//menu size is already image size (by default), no need to set it
menu.position = CGPointMake((self.size.width - menu.size.width) * 0.5,
                            (self.size.height - menu.size.height) * 0.5);
[self addChild:menu];
self.scene.paused = YES;
self.scene.view.paused = YES;
```

Comment: works if i delete self.scene.paused = YES;
    self.scene.view.paused = YES; but i need to pause the background game/ scene aswell.

Comment: @user3423384 Edited. Place them after.

Comment: i've added my code in the question. I've done exactly like you said and if i delete paused code the SKSpriteNode will appear, but not with the pause code.

Comment: @user3423384 What if you remove self.scene.paused = YES;, but left self.scene.view.paused = YES;?

Answer (score 1):

If you **REALLY** want to do this, you call put all your UIImageView stuff from,

```
-(void) didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {}
```

then when you want to call the pausedMenu items you'll have to create a new scene so that `didMoveToView:` gets triggered. A scene specific to the pause menu.

Comment: i've allready created and UIButton inside didMoveToView which will trigger the pausedMenu when clicked and should show the menu (imageView) and pause the scene